# This may slow down the debug session, how can I overcome this?

Tags: iphone, memory-management

I got two error reports like this

> warning: Unable to read symbols for /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/DeviceSupport/5.0.1 (9A405)/Symbols/System/Library/TextInput/Riven.bundle/Riven (file not found).
>   warning: No copy of Riven.bundle/Riven found locally, reading from memory on remote device.  This may slow down the debug session.

and

> [3/22/12 3:42:04 PM] SHINE: 2012-03-22 15:41:29.958 SoundReport[4354:707] setting the first responder view of the table but we don't know its type (cell/header/footer)

Answer (score 0):

Regarding first problem, Its the warning of iOS od sdk, you can not do much to remove it and also it will not effect your app.
For second error you are trying to set becomeFirstResponder I guess so and its in tableView, its tough to say exactly without code.provide some code for the tableView.